# Counting multiple letters in one cell on Excel

Tags: excel, count, pie-chart

[image][image]

I am doing an analysis of bacterial genes and I have a spreadsheet where column A is the gene name and column B has what we call the gene COG categories where depending on what the gene function is (e.g. carbohydrate metabolism, cell movement etc.) it is assigned a letter code (A, B, C... all the way to the letter S).

I would like to make a pie chart to show what the split of the proportion of these letters is - how many As Bs Cs etc I have. However, I have an issue as some of the genes belong to more than one group and so have more than one letter in the cell. Is there a way where I can get Excel to count how many letters there are and each letter be counted individually in the cells with multiple letters in them? (e.g. if a cell had AEI then that would be counted as 1 A, 1E and 1I?)

Comment: Too much science details here and not enough spreadsheet details lol. Can you share some sample inputs/outputs? Unclear how your spreadsheet is formatted so hard to know what kind of formula you are looking for. You can't count instances of a character by measuring the length of the string before and after removing the string but i'm not sure if that fits the output you need

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write that you want to create a Pie chart.

That means you will need to create a 2D array with the letters and their respective frequencies.

One method, if you have Office 365:

**Orig Data**
[image]

- Create a two column table

  - One column with all the letters in the alphabet
  - One column with a count of all those letters

Count Formula:

```
E2: =LEN(CONCAT(COG))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(COG),D2,""))
```

and **fill down** to `E27`

[image]

- Create a filtered table, filtering out the rows where Count = 0

  ```
    G2: =FILTER($D$2:$E$27,$E$2:$E$27<>0)
  ```

[image]

Create your Pie Chart:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need! But unfortunately, I added the formula and it comes up with a NAME error? I've added this as a screenshot to my original question? have I done anything wrong?

Comment: @MicaelaMossop I wrote: "*if you have Office 365*". So, my first question is:  Do you have Office 365?  If not, then what version do you have?

Comment: Yes, I have office 365! I think I have managed to get it to work by changing "COG" with the cell numbers. Thank you so much for your help, you've solved it!

Comment: @MicaelaMossop Ah, `COG` is used as a Named Range. So if you either replace it with the actual reference, or create a `Named RAnge` where COG refers to the cells (either directly or dynamically), it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can count instances of a character by measuring the `LEN` (*length*) of the string before and after removing the target character. The difference in `LEN` is simply the number of times your character is present.

Here is an example of how to use this with the format shared below. Enter formula in cell `B2` and drag across and down as needed

```
B2 = LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1,""))
```

---

To count how many unique letters exist in the string you can just count over the output of above formula looking for count of letters with 1 or more  (i.e. <> 0) with below formula in `H2`

```
H2 = COUNTIF(B2:G2,"<>"&0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the extra science info!! I just wanted to explain the background a bit so it could explain why I wanted to count letters hahah. My spreadsheet is formatted like the screenshot I've just attached, does that change the formula you've posted?

Comment: Nope, just apply the formula to look in column U instead of column A

Comment: If you are unsure how to make this work with your setup, update your screen shot to just show like 5 examples maybe and show the output in the desired format. I.e. show us the start and end so we understand what needs to be done inbetween